# How to re-activate my Command Shift 4 (for screen captures)

Tags: macbook-pro

I need to re-activate my <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (for screen captures). I somehow lost this ability on my MacBook Air.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Open System preferences App then go to Keyboard -> Abbreviations -> In the left panel click Snapshots  "scissor icon" -> Activate abbreviations.

and also...

Open System preferences App then go to Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> In the left panel click screen shots -> select options on right frame.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is with keyboard shortcuts, then open System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Screenshots -> Shortcuts.

Then select "Screen Shots" from the pane on the left and press <kbd>Restore Defaults</kbd> button on the screen.

[image]

---

If the problem is not in the keyboard settings, execute this from the Terminal (no need for `sudo`):

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

And check the result.

You might also check the destination path for the saved screenshots:

```
defaults read com.apple.screencapture
```

If it points to a non-existing path, or if you want to change it, execute:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Pictures/
killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: Right on, seems we both did the same at the same time. Cheers :) Lets edit each others for fun.